# LWJGL - Quad not being rendered

Tags: java, opengl, shader, render, lwjgl

I've been trying to make this piece of code work for a while now and I still can't figure it out what I did wrong. (LWJGL - Java)

I have tried to check on the web for other people's code, but I can't find any major difference. I actually learned to use OpenGL with C++ so my mind might be stuck on it and that might be why I can't find my errors.

Here is the init (called once)

```
FloatBuffer vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4 * 5);
    vertices.put(new float[]{
            // pos                  // Color
            0.5f, 0.5f,             0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,            0.5f, 0.0f, 0.75f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,           0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f,            0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f
    });
    vertices.flip();

    ByteBuffer indices = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(2 * 3);
    indices.put(new byte[]{
            0, 1, 3,
            1, 2, 3
    });
    indices.flip();

    // VAO
    VAO = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    // VBO
    VBO = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // EBO
    EBO = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    //                         v - position in layout (see shader)
    //                            v - Nb of component per vertex (2 for 2D (x, y))
    //                                                v - Normalized ? (between 0 - 1)
    //                                                       v - Offset between things (size of a line)
    //                                                                     v - Where to start ?
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * Float.SIZE , 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * Float.SIZE , 2 * Float.SIZE);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

    // Unbinds the VAO
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

And here is the render function :

```
shaderProgram.bind();

GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAO);

GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL11.GL_BYTE, 0);

GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec4 Color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    Color = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Framgent :

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 Color;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = Color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the the [official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html), `Float.SIZE` is defined as:

> The number of **bits** used to represent a float value.

Since `glVertexAttribPointer()` expects the stride and offset arguments in bytes, you will have to divide this by 8, and use `(Float.SIZE / 8)` instead.

Comment: Doesn't seems to do anything. It's pretty hard to debug since I can't have access to the attributes